# Using xmlParser in CodeBlocks

Tags: xml, mingw, codeblocks

I´m trying to use XmlParser in Codeblocks, compiling under MinGW, but I keep getting undefined references on specific functions. I´ve been searching all over the Internet but can´t find an answer. Anyone have managed to use it?

Comment: Are you linking to the library

Comment: Yes, I´m linking it. I´m even using other libraries in the same program but only XmlParser doesn´t seem to work.

Comment: Add your linker settings to the question.